# Word Spacing in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

CSS has a property called `word-spacing`, which allows you to justify the size of the space between different words. An example would be something like

`Hello world
vs.
Hello     world`

Is there a way to accomplish this same effect in a `UILabel` in Objective-C? I've looked though the [class reference for NSParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but there doesn't seem to be an option. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any features in `UILabel` that allow you to do that.  The alternative is to create a custom subclass of `UIView`, and then override the `drawRect` method to draw your text anyway you like.

Here's a sample `drawRect` method.  The code draws the first string near the left side of the label.  The second string is drawn 15 points to the right of the first string. The third string is drawn near the right side of the label.  (All strings are centered vertically.) The resulting label looks like this
[image]

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSString *str;
    NSArray *strArray = @[ @"First", @"Second", @"Third" ];
    CGSize strSize[strArray.count];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : self.font };
    int i = 0;
    for ( str in strArray )
        strSize[i++] = [str sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

    int y = (self.bounds.size.height - strSize[0].height) / 2;

    // draw the first string 4 points from the left edge
    [strArray[0] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake( 4, y ) withAttributes:attributes];

    // draw the second string 15 points to the right of the first string
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake( 4 + strSize[0].width + 15, y );
    [strArray[1] drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:attributes];

    // draw the third string 4 points from the right edge
    point = CGPointMake( self.bounds.size.width - 4 - strSize[2].width, y );
    [strArray[2] drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:attributes];
}
```